# array.push(SomeObject) does not copy an array contained in SomeObject

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, node.js

The following code:

```
var ResultSet= { 'ResultSetName': "Resultset1",
    Values: [ { Val1: 1, Val2: 2, Val3: 'SomeName' } ] }

var AllResults= { 'MyListName': 'SomeList', 'MyResults': { Results: [] } }


AllResults.MyResults.Results.push(ResultSet);

console.log(AllResults.MyResults);
console.log(AllResults.MyResults.Values);
```

Produces the output:

```
{ Results: [ { ResultSetName: 'Resultset1', Values: [Object] } ] }
undefined
```

However I would expect it to produce something like:

```
{ Results: [ { ResultSetName: 'Resultset1', Values: [Object] } ] }
[ { Val1: 1, Val2: 2, Val3: 'SomeName' } ]
```

What Am I missing? Why is the array contained in the object not copied? What would be the correct way to achieve the desired result?

(I'm using node.js 1.8.2, but I het the same behavior in a browser)

Answer (score 1):

AllResults is an object.
AllResults.MyResults is an object
AllResults.MyResults.Results is an array

AllResults.MyResults.Results[0] is your `ResultSet` object.

```
console.log(AllResults.MyResults.Results[0].Values); //This is where your Values object ended up.
```